# C# attribute with complex structure

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

EDIT: looks like it's not possible to have only one attribute with everything inside like solution #2, so I ended up using solution #3 which is not error prone unlike solution #1.

I have an attribute as follow:

```
// Solution #1 (working)
[Module(Name="Module1", Guid="xxxxx",
  NeededFiles_Name = new string[]
  {
    "module1Conf.xml",
    "module1.sql",
    "resourcesWindows",
    "resourcesUnix",
  },
  NeededFiles_OS = new OSType[]
  {
    All,
    All,
    Windows,
    Unix,
  }
  NeededFiles_Component = new ComponentType[]
  {
    Server,
    Server,
    All,
    All
  }
)]
```

The problem is that it's not easy to fill the NeededFile_Xxx properties. It would be easier to have only one property like

```
// Solution #2 (NOT working)
[Module(Name="Module1", Guid="xxxxx",
  NeededFile = new FileInfo[]
  {
    new FileInfo("module1Conf.xml", All, Server),
    ...
  }
)]
```

but it's not allowed by the compiler (*NeededFile is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type*.

I could also divide my attribute into severals and do

```
// Solution #3 (working)
[Module(Name="Module1", Guid="xxxxx"]
[NeededFile("module1Conf.xml", All, Server)]
[NeededFile("module1.sql", All, Server)]
[NeededFile(...)]
```

but I'd rather keep everything in the same.

Is it possible to do it? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I like the second option better.

Comment: @Richard Schneider I agree. It's easier to read, much less error prone, and it even looks to take less work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<strike>Why isn't it (you second option) allowed?  I just tried the following:</strike>

```
public class MyFileInfo
{
    public MyFileInfo(string fname, string somethingElse, string anotherThing);
}

public class ModuleAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public ModuleAttribute(string Name, string Guid, params MyFileInfo[] myFileInfoList)
    {
    }
}

[Module("Module1", "xxxx",
    new MyFileInfo("a", "b", "c"),
    new MyFileInfo("a", "d", "f"))
]
public class TestClass
{
}
```

And the compiler didn't complain.  I think you can achieve pretty much exactly what you're trying to do.

Edit: that's what I get for letting intellisense do my compiling for me in the middle of the night after a couple beers.  As you (and I) have discovered, Attribute arguments must be constants, or lists of constants - a restriction that explicitly excludes classes and structs.

I think the best you're going to be able to do is pass in a serialized version of the data you're trying to tag onto the attribute.  Then the attribute constructor can do the actual object initialization at runtime.  This loses compile-time checking of your initializers, but gets you a bit closer to the compactness of code you were looking for.

```
public class MyFileInfo
{
    string fname;
    string anotherThing;
    string somethingElse;
    public MyFileInfo(string serializedFileInfo)
    {
        string[] parts = serializedFileInfo.Split(',');
        fname = parts[0];
        anotherThing = parts[1];
        somethingElse = parts[2];
    }
    public static implicit operator MyFileInfo(string things)
    {
        return new MyFileInfo(things);
    }
}

public class ModuleAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    List<MyFileInfo> fiList;
    public ModuleAttribute(string Name, string Guid, params string[] serializedFileInfoList)
    {
        fiList = serializedFileInfoList.Select(s => new MyFileInfo(s)).ToList();
    }
}

[Module("Module1", "xxxx",
    "a,b,c",
    "d,e,f"
    )
]
public class TestClass
{
}
```

Really though, I think you should just handle it through a separate attribute for each file.

Comment: Actually for my 2nd option I thought of using a named attribute (which isn't allowed by the compiler: "xxx is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type"), I simply didn't thought of adding "params MyFileInfo[]" to the constructor!

Thanks a lot, I knew there had to be a better way to go!

Comment: I just realized your solution doesn't compile on my PC! I tried on VS2008 as well as MonoDevelop with .Net 4...I just can't do a "new MyFileInfo" as it tells me "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type". Also I had to write "{}" instead of ";" for MyFileInfo (might just be a mistake on your part though).

Comment: Thanks for the other way to do it, but I'd rather be able to use Intellisense. As for losing the compile-time checking, it's always possible to use some unit test: that's what I use when I have a string representing a Guid, or a string representing an assembly qualified class name (useful if the class is in another assembly). So eventually I'll just go with the separate attribute for each file...